# How to Open multiple tabs on google chrome with different discord account

Tags: javascript, request, discord

I got 8 discord accounts to farm a game, and it is boring to always open 8 tabs and fill 8 times the mail and the password.

Is there any way to automate it ? Like i open a file and it opens a chrome window with 8 tabs connected to discord, each one diferent account.

I was thinking of copying the code and just fill the input but it doesn't seem to work :/

Thank you for reading!!